# Jupyter Notebook not connecting to local port

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have one environment that I install jupyter with `conda install jupyter` and activate the environment that jupyter is installed, I install other dependencies also and was able to to work with jupyter for sometime,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDUwg.png)

the image shows that there is a port in use and consecutively other ports are  tested to launch the development env,

when I command `jupyter` the following is displayed
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akaob.png)

It seems to be the connections with the ports, but still jupyter looks for a free port to connect to.

Comment: What if you point your browser to `localhost:8874`, which is the address displayed in the Jupyter console?

Comment: Still have the same outcome